# Preventing Duplicated Google Maps API Marker use ValueEventListener Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to make a marker in my app using google maps api and I got the location from my RLTB Firebase. The location is always changing so that is why I was using ValueEventListener.

I tried to setting the marker outside of ValueEvent but does not work properly.

```
getDataNewLoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location").child(id_diriku);
        getDataNewLoc.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Double new_lat = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("l").child("0").getValue();
                Double new_long = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("l").child("1").getValue();

                LatLng diriku = new LatLng(new_lat, new_long);

                mDiriku = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("Diriku")
                        .position(diriku)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_forme))
                );
                mDiriku.setTag(0);
                mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(diriku, 19.0f ) );
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

How could I prevent this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the location information from the database once, use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

So:

```
getDataNewLoc.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following line at the top, inside the onDataChange method

```
mMap.clear()
```